# Linked server change have an affect on current OPENQUERY

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

Just had a linked server added (from PGADMIN) in SSMS which when we try to access the tables gives us the error in the screenshot. Our report server is in SSMS so any data that is held in PGADMIN that re require, we use OPEN QUERY to pull this through.

[image]

I've found a potential fix for the error by going into the odbc connection and adjusting character length

[image]

My question is... will changing this on the linked server have an affect on any current stored procedures/OPEN QUERIES we have that are using the tables from PGADMIN?

Comment: *"Our report server is in SSMS"* so are you using some kind of adding for SSMS? SSMS isn't really designed as a reporting tool, it's an IDE-like application.

Comment: Forgive my language, I guess its an instance which has been named report server by our infrastructure team. I was just trying to get across that we predominantly write our queries in SSMS which frequently use OPEN QUERY and any change mention above may impact them?